# handleExpand function is changing multiple Material UI cards in the grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

My coworker has created a grid using Material UI; each row in the grid has 3-5 Material UI cards, and each card needs to have an "expand" option to show more detail. For each row in the grid, we're using redux/hooks to pull in data; each record has the same fields (e.g. each record might have a "name", "year", etc. field). The issue we're running into is that when we expand the "name" card on one row of the grid, it expands all "name" cards in the grid. I've been trying to find a solution, but haven't come up with anything. Here's the link  to the codesandbox with sample data:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-stallman-jtjss?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each card-container that you have should implement it's own expand/collapse functionality.

You can create a new component that wraps specific card (for example `<CardWrapper />)` and that component will have it's own state (expandedName, setExpandedName) and so on.

A quick and dirty solution might look like this:

```
const CardWrapper = (dataExample) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  [expandedName, setExpandedName] = useState(false);
  const handleExpandClickName = () => {
    setExpandedName(!expandedName)
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid>
        <Card>
           <CardActions disableSpacing>
             <IconButton
               key={dataExample.key}
               className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                 [classes.expandOpen]: expandedName,
               })}
               onClick={() => dispatch(handleExpandClickName)}
               aria-expanded={expandedName}
               aria-label="show more"
             >
               <ExpandMoreIcon />
             </IconButton>
           </CardActions>
           <Collapse in={expandedName} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
             <CardContent>
               <Typography paragraph>Test</Typography>
             </CardContent>
           </Collapse>
         </Card>
       </Grid>
    </div>);
}
```

And inside your code you should use something like this:

```
const ServiceAreaTile = () => {
  const psOverviewSA = useSelector((state) => state.psOverviewSA);

  return psOverviewSA.map((dataExample) => {
    return (<CardWrapper dataExample={dataExample} />);
  }
}
```

This way the expand state is being kept internally for each CardWrapper, and they don't have any collisions between them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I'm having the same issue; the "name" card on each grid line is still expanding/collapsing whenever I click on any of them. I'm thinking that there is maybe a way I can reference a specific key in the handle change function, but I haven't found a way to make it work yet.

Comment: Can you create a working example? You can use https://codesandbox.io for that.

Comment: Here is a very simplified example; notice that, whenever you click on any of the ProductID expand icons, all of the ProductID cards expand. https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-stallman-jtjss?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You need to save the codesandbox. There is nothing there currently.

Comment: SO SORRY, just saved it!

Comment: Please try to open the link in a new incognito window.

Comment: I think I forgot to save the products.json file changes the first time (my apologies, I've never actually shared anything from codesandbox before!). Now it seems to work when I open in an incognito window.

Comment: I don't see anything that you changed based on my answer. It seems like it's the original code that you showed on the question.

Comment: The good news is that the expand buttons now work independently (thank you!); the bad news is that the cards now aren't referencing the data in the products.json file.

Comment: Again, based on your code in the codesandbox I don't see my suggestion for how to implement it. You are welcome to update the code and let me know.

Comment: When I open the link above in an incognito window it opens with the code changes you suggested; I don't understand why it's not showing you the same thing it's showing me?

Comment: Now I see what you did there, and it's not what I wrote. You just wrapped your entire code with the `CardWrapper`, but this is not what I suggested. You should have 1 component that is called `CardWrapper` (that wraps the `<Card>` component from material), and in your App you should not use the `<Card>`. Instead you should use the `<CardWrapper>`.  The CardWrapper should wrap **only 1 Card**. It's a CardWrapper. Not CardsWrapper :-).

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! I implemented the changes in my actual code and it worked!